# HTML tags not rendering in UIWebView?

Tags: xcode, swift, encoding, uiwebview

I have a blog. The content is stored in an MS SQL database, with HTML tags included.  I output the data as JSON and load it into a UIWebView, but the tags are appearing as text.  What am I don't wrong?  Just a portion of the blog text from database here:

<p class="p1"><span class="s1">The Yonkers Industrial Development agency&nbsp;(YIDA) &nbsp;gave initial approval to a new craft brewery in the downtown waterfront area. The brewery's working title is Chicken Island Brewery.</span></p>

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some code of how you're loading the HTML into your web view? A normal implementation should look like `webView.loadHTMLString(string: "<html><body><p>Hello world</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to access the method `loadHTMLString` from the webview. For example:

```
var htmlString:String! = "<br /><h2>Welcome to SourceFreeze!!!</h2>"
myWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

Source code taken from: http://sourcefreeze.com/uiwebview-example-using-swift-in-ios/

Comment: I'm using loadHTMLString... Must the html have <html> <body> tags?
I'm having an issue with the print statement in XCode.  It prints output differently that the JSON which makes this hard to debug.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can use NSAttributedString

```
let theAttributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: "Your String".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!,
                                                          options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                                                          documentAttributes: nil)
```